# How to make the colors of the Mac more dull/faded?

Tags: display, color, accessibility, productivity

For more than a year I've had my phone in black & white mode and I find it greatly helps reduce the stimulating effect of using the phone, and makes me naturally use the phone less (and it's more calming etc). I feel way more productive!

On the desktop I can't go completely black and white (which is available in the Accessibility settings) because I do have lots of apps that rely on color, however;

**Is there a way in MacOS (via an ICC color profile, ColorSync app etc) to somehow change the color of my Mac monitor (either built-in display or thunderbolt display) to be "faded"/"dull" - almost geryscale but with a hint of color?**

When I run the Display Calibration or Go into Accessibility settings I seem to only be able to change the hue, but what I'm looking for is to have a nice and bright setup that is just less colorful (so literally greyscale with faded/hint of color).

Anyone know how one might be able to do that?

Comment: After SysPref>Display>Colour, press Option ket before clicking Calibrate. This gives you advanced settings.  Might help, but I don't think that is your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Displays and click on the Color tab. You should see several different profiles on the left.  Select one you don't expect to use and select it and then select Open Profile on the right. I don't know what all the numbers mean but you could try trial and error to maybe get a color profile more to your liking.

Comment: The above got me close enough to a solution. Basically, unless I'm doing something wrong it doesn't look like I can change the color profiles, however if under "Displays" -> "Color" you uncheck "Show profiles for this display only" then you can select a profile called "Wide Gamut RGB" which is a bit faded, would be nice if it was even more faded but this is ok for a start, thanks @jmh! (also good feedback from @Gilby - that almost worked - you can almost create a good profile that way but there doesn't quite seem to be the levers I was looking for - the outcomes always affected the legibility)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'd meet you requirement, but perhaps adjusting the colour temperature of your display may help? `System Preferences` > `Displays` > `Night Shift`.

[image: Display > Colour Temperature]

If your macOS release doesn't have that option, another option is the free third-party application [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/). f.lux has more options that Night Shift, so you may also prefer it.